# How to update an HTML5 table after deleting an item

Tags: angular, rest, api, typescript

**On restaurant.component.ts**

I want to delete an item from `arrayList` and update it after delete. The query is performing delete operation but the list is not getting updated. I'm calling the `ngOnInit()` method but nothing happens

```
ngOnInit() {
this.restaurantesService.GetRestaurantes()
.subscribe((restaurantes => {
  this.restaurantes  = restaurantes;
}))
```

}

```
 qDeleteRestaurantes(CODIGO: number){
var restaurantes = this.restaurantes;
this.restaurantesService.DeleteRestaurantes(CODIGO)
.subscribe((data) => { if (data.n ==1 ){
  for(let i=0;i<restaurantes.length;i++){
    if(restaurantes[i].CODIGO == CODIGO){
      this.restaurantes.splice(i,1);
      this.ngOnInit();

     }        
  } 
}})
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you are hittin the `if` so that `ngOnInit` is called again. Also as a comment, do not call `ngOnInit`, instead just call the request again to fetch the rastaurants. Also then why are you doing the `splice` if you want to fetch the restaurants again after that. `splice` is redundant since you are fetching the restaurants again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your restaurant.service, declare a variable,

```
restaurants: restaurants[];
```

On your qDeleteRestaurant(CODIGO: number), assign

```
this._restaurantService.restaurants = this.restaurants;
```

Of course, in your constructor, declare

```
 private _restaurantService: RestaurantService,..
```

**You need to implement DoCheck,

```
ngDoCheck(){
  this.restaurants = this._restaurantService.restaurants;
}
```

This approach is what I use in my shopping cart to delete, add, update. Good luck.

[image]

Comment: Did you try implementing ngDoCheck? Have a nice day.